# Does every right-continuous function have left limits?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $t \mapsto f(t)$ be a right-continuous function such that every $s\leq \infty$, $\lim_{q\uparrow s}f(q) $ exists and is finite. Here $q\uparrow s$ means we approach $s$ along the rationals. Is it then true that every $s\leq \infty$, $\lim_{t\uparrow s}f(t) $ exists and is finite, $t\uparrow s$ being an arbitrary sequence approaching $s$?

Comment: in the title you ask for **left** limits... As for your question, the rationals are dense in the reals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$, $s>0$, and let $\ell=\lim_{q\uparrow s}f(q)$ be the left
limit taken over the rationals. For every $t<s$, right continuity at $t$
allows us to select $q\in(t,s)$ so that $f(q)-\varepsilon\leq f(t)\leq f(q)+\varepsilon.$

If $t_n\uparrow s,$ we let $q_n$ be the corresponding rationals so that 
$$f(q_n)-\varepsilon\leq f(t_n)\leq f(q_n)+\varepsilon.\tag1 $$
Letting $n\to\infty$ in (1) gives 
$$\ell-\varepsilon\leq \liminf_n f(t_n)\leq \limsup_n f(t_n)\leq \ell+\varepsilon, $$
and since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $\lim_{t\uparrow s}f(t)$
exists and is equal to $\ell$.